# Map list of objects with condition

Tags: list, kotlin

I have a list of objects, I would like make something like this

```
myobjectList = myObjectList.map{ if( !listObjectIDontWantModify.contains(it) it.copy(value = newvalue)}
```

But return List. I just want modify some objects but keeping all objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
myObjectList = myObjectList.map {
    if (it !in listObjectIDontWantModify) it.copy(value = newValue)
    else it
}
```